# Cannot execute Java binary file in Mac Terminal

Tags: java, macbook, eclipse

I am trying to run IBM Java on Mac terminal but which is giving error,

```
./java -version

-bash: ./java: cannot execute binary file
```

Here is the terminal detail

```
uname -a

Darwin Devendras-MacBook-Pro.local 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Also, the Java version as seen in a RHEL server, is,

```
./java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr9fp50-20160720_02(SR9fp50))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160630_309948 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR9_20160630_1817_B309948
JIT  - tr.r11_20160630_120374
GC   - R26_Java726_SR9_20160630_1817_B309948_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160630_309948)
JCL - 20160719_01 based on Oracle jdk7u111-b13
```

And I want to use this Java on my MacBook, for Eclipse or for testing. However, with the above error I cannot do anything.

Comment: So, I see that both OS and the IBM java are 64 bit, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a proper answer:

It appears you just copied over some Java runtime/SDK from your RHEL machine to a macOS machine. This won’t work; Linux executables cannot run on macOS.

To make this work, you need a macOS version of the Java SDK. IBM does *not* appear to provide this. As such, you will have to use a different Java SDK. If it is critical that you use the IBM Java SDK, you’ll have to use a virtual machine (Parallels, VMware Fusion, VirtualBox, QEMU, …) to run Linux on your macOS machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure java is in your PATH environment? It seems like not. Can you try /bin/java or something like that:

```
/bin/java -version
```

Comment: yeah, JAVA is not there in the PATH,

**>/bin/java -version
-bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory**

Comment: default java is set though,

**>java -version

java version "1.8.0_141"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)**

Comment: What are you trying to run though ?

Based on this line:
    - bash: /Users/dev/Documents/1/1WORK/_2018/jdk7sr9fp50/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
, it seems like you are not running the default java binary. I don't have any problem running eclipse with default java. 

Just in case, you could re-install or update your current version of java , here is a link [http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/javaforosx.dmg] and re-try.

Comment: Yeah, default java runs fine.
However, I want to run IBM JDK from mac terminal, which is real issue.